# How to add a button in rqt?

Tags: ros, rqt

I have done some research on how to make a button in rqt and I came across [this](https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_visualization/blob/master/doc/jsk_rqt_plugins/plugins/rqt_service_buttons.md) option from [jsk](https://jsk-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jsk_visualization/doc/jsk_rqt_plugins/). I have downloaded the jsk package from [github](https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_visualization). Now that I have the plugin installed how do I actually get the push button example to run in rqt? Could someone walk me threw the steps I need to do to get the downloaded example to appear in an rqt window. Thank you very much to anyone who can help I am using ubunto 16.04 and ros kinetic. I have an existing perspective file I would like to implement this on.

Comment: Since you have installed the plugin it should be available in the plugins menu of rqt. Isn't it?

Comment: all I did was download it it is not showing up @Fruchtzwerg

Comment: ROS can't recognize the plu ins only by downloading them. You should think about installing the package like `apt-get install ros-kinetic-jsk-common` (use the correct distro!). Now the plugin should be available.

Comment: had to run that command with sudo but as far as I can tell nothing has changed I don't have any new plugins available in rqt @Fruchtzwerg

Comment: Which ROS distro are you using? Did you installed the correct package ?

Comment: I am using kinetic as stated before @Fruchtzwerg

Comment: it is saying that some of the files failed to download @Fruchtzwerg this might be the problem?

Comment: Sure, sounds like the installation failed?